# WhenAll for anonymous type containing a Task

Tags: c#, async-await, anonymous-class

Is it possible to await a anonymous object (or Tuple, don't care) that contains a Task...better to explain with code...

Lets says we have this:

```
async Task<Item> GetItem(int i);
```

**Basic case (works):**

```
var itemTasks = new []{1,2,3}.Select(i => GetItem(i)).toArray();
Item[] items = await Task.WhenAll(itemTasks);
```

**what I want to do**

```
var itemTasks = new []{1,2,3}
    .Select(i => new { MyItem = GetItem(i), TheNumber = i })
    .toArray();
//some way to wait for all and get a collection of<anynomous type above>
```

Comment: Is the `GetItem` the same as `getItem`? C# is a case sensitive language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to make your lambda `async`:

```
var itemTasks = new []{ 1, 2, 3 }
    .Select(async i => new { MyItem = await GetItem(i), TheNumber = i });

var anonymousObjects = await Task.WhenAll(itemTasks);
```

The `async` lambda will implicitly return a `Task<AnonymousObject>`.

---

As an aside, your `ToArray()` is superfluous, because `Task.WhenAll` enumerates the `Task`s anyway.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks Johnathan! yes, true. I think that was from some work in progress. thanks for your help!

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` will copy all the tasks to an internal array before returning.